# Is there a way to access to an index value while iterating over a Map object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project I had to convert a Javascript Object into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object called *mapResults*. After some transformations (slicing out the first two values) I now want to iterate over this collection to render some list items with the following syntax.

- {key1}:{value1}
- {key2}:{value2}

The thing is that I also have an array called *resultsKey* with strings that I want to use as {keys} for every list item. So, lets say that my Map object and my strings array look like this:

```
mapResults = 
0: gameStatus -> "You Won!"
1: difficulty -> "Intermediate"
2: movesCount -> 13

resultsKey = [
"Final result",
"Level",
"Number of movements",
]
```

Now I would like to iterate over both collections to get the desired list item output as:

- Final result : You Won!

Where every key of the list item its taken from my resultsKey array and every value is taken from my mapResults object. Both collections are the same length/size.

I know that if I had an Object object (name it *objectResults*)instead of a Map object, I could achieve this by calling Object.keys() on the Object, and then calling .map() or forEach() on the resulting array (lets call it *objectResultsKeys*) like this:

```
objectResultsKeys.map((key, index)=>{
    return <li>
        {resultsKey[index]}:{objectResults[key]}
        </li>
})
```

The thing here is, that if I had this situation I would be able to use the **index** parameter that the .map() function provides to access the resultsKey strings array and obtain the value I want. But there is no such thing when it comes to [iterating over Map objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_for..of).

So what I want to know is if there is any solution that provides me with and index value that I can use to access my strings array while iterating over the Map object. Or if there is any other solution to achieve a similar outcome to what I've explained. Im constrained to use a Map object for this solution.

Comment: Although Maps have a certain order, they are still meant to be an unordered collection of key/value pairs. If you need a certain order a Map is the wrong choice.

Comment: I don't understand, `Map` has a `forEach` method.  Why aren't you using that?  That **is** iterating over a `Map`.

Comment: What is it that you dont understand? I can try to expand. I can use a forEach, but how would that allow me  acces to an index value to obtain the desired string from my strings array?

Answer (score 3):

You could just take a counter:

```
 let index = 0;
 for(const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
   // ...
   index++;
 }
```

Or you turn the entries into an array:

```
 [...map.entries()].forEach(([key, value], index) =>
   //...
 );
```

But actually as Maps are ordered by insertion time I would not rely on the Maps order.